# Continuous function $\geq 0$ on dense subset

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I'd like to use this fact, but I couldn't find out, how to prove it. Assume we have a continuous function $f : X \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ with $X$ a topological space and $f \vert_D \geq 0$ on a dense subset $D \subset X$. Can I conclude that $f \geq 0$ on the whole space $X$?

I know that a function is uniquely determined by its restriction to a dense subset. But how can I use that to prove the fact?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $f(x)<0$ then it would be $<0$ on some neighbourhood of $x$. This neighbourhood must contain a point of $D$.

Comment: Oh boy, I completely overlooked that. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

$f^{-1}([0,+\infty[)$ is closed and contains the dense subspace $D$ thus is $X$

Answer (score 0):

Take $x\in X$. If $x\in D$, you done. If not, there exists $(x_n)\in D^{\mathbb{N}}$ converging to $x$, since $\bar{D}=X$. Then $$0\leq f(x_n)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}f(x)$$
using continuity of $f$.

**Edit:** not sufficient for general topological spaces, cf. comment below. I'm leaving this answer here exactly because of this (I found the discussion in the comments useful, at least for me, to understand some of the concepts at play.)

Comment: For general topological spaces, you need filters or nets, sequences don't suffice.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you... my days of general topology seem far. (What is the minimum structure needed on $X$ for the above argument to work?)

Comment: $X$ is not assumed separated

Comment: @TsemoAristide Whether $X$ is Hausdorff or not doesn't matter. What matters is that the codomain, $\mathbb{R}$, is Hausdorff.

Comment: I'm undeleting my question, for my own sake: basically, what part in the above fails, and what is the assumption missing for it to go through? (I actually never heard of nets nor filter, so there is an assumption in the memories of topology I have that I have missed, and that's itching.)

Comment: @ClementC. The minimum structure for sequences to suffice would be that the space is sequential - which is kind of tautological. First countable spaces are sequential, so first countability would be a non-tautological sufficient condition. But If you just replace the sequence with a net or filter, the argument goes through for all topological spaces.

Comment: i have read his proof, and his characterization of the adherence of D suppose D is closed

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks. I guess "metric" space was the thing I was missing as assumption (since these are sequential, and basically the "next thing after general topological spaces" my curriculum non-trivially covered.)